# SAP HANA Analytical Views

Tags: hana, denormalization

I have been trying to learn HANA these past few days and have been getting some problems.

So, as I see SAP HANA is used for de-normalization of data (as per some tutorials that I have seen). So I make the analytic views and I have my data denormalized after making the analytical views.

What next? How do I harness/use these views to create reports for business analysis?

I need to generate several reports based on this de-normalized data (which I intend to ultimately use for a website based product).

Do I need to create different Analytical views for different reports?

Comment: check this out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 1):

HANA is not for denormalization of your data. You don't have to create aggregate and denormalized tables to speed up your analytics. In a normal analytics scenario you might build these but this will result in duplicate data, double maintenance to keep these up date etc..

Instead of this you can use your normal normalized database tables as a master/transactional data foundation and then build analytic views on these. How many views have to be created for different reports depends on your actual business needs, because views contain data in many aspects so they can be reused. In case of more complex reports you can of course create calculation views to get the exact data you need.

HTH